# How can I find videos with subtitles in Esperanto?

Tags: culture, technology

I'm using Amara to translate video subtitles into Esperanto, and I was wondering if there is some way to find out when a new subtitle in Esperanto is available for a video. 
I guess I can do a search on Youtube, but it would be really useful to be able to set up an rss-feed with new videos as they become available.

Comment: This may only help a little, but you can get team-specific subtitled videos in Esperanto using a URL query like this: https://amara.org/en/teams/ted/videos/?q=&project=tedtalks&lang-mode=%2B&lang=eo&sort=-time

Comment: The title says you want to find subtitles that are in Esperanto, but the body of the question implies you want to find subtitles in other languages so that you can translate them. Could you perhaps clarify this?

Comment: Oh, I actually meant new *Esperanto* subtitles. I’ll change that!

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one way to see the latest videos with Esperanto subtitles on Amara. Sadly it’s not super convenient.

This link will get you a list of all the videos with Esperanto subtitles:

https://amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&langs=eo

If you look at the bottom of the page, it tells you how many pages of 20 videos there are:

> 1 - 20 of 1253 videos

If you divide that number by 20, you can work out a link to the last page to see the latest videos like this:

https://amara.org/en/search/#/?q=&langs=eo&page=62